# CAS Services ACL

Tags: java, authentication, single-sign-on, cas

I am wondering if Central Authentication Service (CAS, http://www.jasig.org/cas) can be configured to block access to specific services on a per-user basis (or based on roles or something!).

Basically, I have two services: http://service1.com & http://service2.com
Users A, B, & C have access to http://service1.com but only A can access http://service2.com.

Is this possible with CAS? I thinking its not since it seems to defeat the purpose of SSO.
If not, what SSO can do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it certainly is. See this link for more info:
http://www.mail-archive.com/cas-dev@lists.jasig.org/msg02993.html

For additional inquiries, please post a message to @cas-dev and we'd be happy to help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the help. We actually went another route and overrode and added some extra classes.